# Cant able to solve:Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : no such table : tablename

Tags: sqlite, sqldf

I am getting this error in shiny.I am using `sqldf` and `SQLite` and trying to get data from database.I followed some of the example of this site.but not working for me.

```
library(sqldf)
library(RSQLite)
library(rlang)
  drv <- "SQL Server"
 drv <- dbDriver("SQLite")
con <- dbConnect(drv, server="xxx" user="ram", password="xxx", dbname="yyy")
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "select * from tablename")
```

Comment: Are you sure that all your connection parameters are correct?

Comment: yes i m sure...

Comment: One could check names using `DBI::dbListTables(con)`.